# Window.print() and cloud printing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, asp.net, google-cloud-print

My application is developed in ASP.NET 
   In one of my pages(`productinfo.aspx`) I have a HTML button named & labelled
   as `print`. I am handling the click of this button in java script like
   below.

```js
$('#print').click(function($)
{
window.print();
});
```

The above is **working fine** in all browsers on PC and in smartphones as well
   **except Google Nexus mobiles and tablets**. It is working in other android
   mobiles like Samsung and Sony experia etc..

I came to know that window.print is not supported in Google android and I 
   should use Google cloud print based on the following link.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

But this requires the user to be logged into to GCP with their Google ID.
   But my requirement is like the device will be not connected to Internet 
   and it should provide the print as dialog as like in other devices.

Note:
   In Android chrome browsers there is a print command in the browsers menu 
   clicking on that is showing the print dialog without any GCP.

Is it possible to invoke the browsers menu command through java script,
   I tired simulating (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) key press event on the button click assuming 
   that it will trigger the browser's print command it too didn't work.

It would be very much helpful if any one can help me with a solution for 
   this issue.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?